# Confusion about discrete distrubition evaluation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose we have the following question:

Consider rolling a fair six-sided die, so that $S = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$.

Let $X(s) = s$,
and $Y(s) = s^3 + 2$. Let $Z = XY$. Compute $Z(s)$ for all s ∈ S.

---

My textbook says the following:

[image]

---

Basically what this means is that $Z(2)=X(2)Y(2)=(2)(2^3+2)=20$

---

However, why can't we think of it like this:

Since we have $Z=XY$, if $Z=2$, that leads to two scenarios, that is, $X=1,Y=2$ or $X=2, Y=1$

So, 
$Z(z=2)=P(x=2,y=1)+P(x=1,y=2)$

What's wrong with my thinking here? Why would the above not work?

Comment: Are you trying to compute the sample space for Z? Or the pmf of Z?

Comment: Sorry the pmf, it should be $Z(z=2)

Comment: Your thinking is correct.

Comment: However, is it possible to obtain a y-value of 1 or 2? This would require an x-value equal to or less than zero.

Comment: Exactly, $P(Y=1)=P(Y=2)=0$. Hence, my thinking would lead to a value of $0$, which is incorrect. This is where the confusion lies.

Comment: You are asked to compute $Z(s)$ for all $s \in S$, which is different from $P(Z = z)$. You seem to know how to compute $Z(s)$. Is your question how to compute $P(Z = z)$, where $z \in \{ Z(s) : s \in S \}$?

Comment: @snarski I think this is where my confusion was. When we are asked to compute the $Z(s)$, then it is valid for us to just plug in each $s$. But when it asks to plug in $Z(z)$ it refers to the pmf, in which case it is different